# integration factor in first order linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why is the constant ignored in ODEs? That is, why can $e^{\int a(x)\,dx}$ be written as $$e^{A(x) + C}$$ and not $$e^{A(x)}?$$

Comment: Do you mean $e^{A(x) + C} = e^{A(x)}e^C = Ce^{A(x)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you multiply by this integrating factor, the $e^C$ will divide cleanly from both sides as a constant.